# Unity Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll not picking up any colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I have the following relatively simple code.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameRTSController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 startPosition; 
    void Update() {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            startPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            Debug.Log(startPosition + " " + Input.mousePosition);
            Collider2D[] collider2DArray = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(startPosition, Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.Log(collider2DArray);
            foreach (Collider2D collider2D in collider2DArray) {
                Debug.Log(collider2D);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But I'm unable to detect any of the colliders in the scene.

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Hmm okay, what makes you think that this is not C#?

Comment: i see the confusion

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Comment: `mousePosition` is in pixel coordinates and `OverlapAreaAll` requires positions in world space